# Gradient on sankey diagram

Tags: highcharts, sankey-diagram

I have a little problem with gradient in sankey diagram.
My sankey diagram look like this
[sankey diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8naO.png)

I don't know how to set gradient to flow from first node to second node, etc. I'd like to create like this
[sankey diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4997Y.gif)

At this time I have done something like this
[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zxL20keo/) but this isn't what i want to.

My JS code include only sankeyChart class look like this

```
function sankeyChart() {
    var sankey = Highcharts.chart('container', {
        title: {
            text: 'Sankey Diagram'
        },

        series: [{
            keys: ['from', 'to', 'weight'],
            data: [],
            type: 'sankey',
            name: ''
        }],
        plotOptions: {
            series: {
                colorByPoint: true
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });

    function setData(data) {
        sankey.series[0].update({
            data: data,
        }, true);
    }

    return {
        'chart': sankey,
        'setData': setData
    }
}
```

I'll be grateful for any idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can overwrite `pointAttribs` method and set the gradient in the way you want:

```
var H = Highcharts;

H.seriesTypes.sankey.prototype.pointAttribs = function(point, state) {
    var opacity = this.options.linkOpacity,
        color = point.color;

    if (state) {
        opacity = this.options.states[state].linkOpacity || opacity;
        color = this.options.states[state].color || point.color;
    }

    return {
        fill: point.isNode ?
            color : {
                linearGradient: {
                    x1: 0,
                    x2: 1,
                    y1: 0,
                    y2: 0
                },
                stops: [
                    [0, H.color(color).setOpacity(opacity).get()],
                    [1, H.color(point.toNode.color).setOpacity(opacity).get()]
                ]
            }
    };
}
```

Live demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/w3qgu497/

Docs: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/extending-highcharts/extending-highcharts

Comment: Wow this is incredibly valuable answer!